# Where is this header file?

Tags: ros, c++, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was looking at some code and noticed a header file that doesn't exist in the repo. [This line](https://github.com/appliedAI-Initiative/orb_slam_2_ros/blob/e978a2c1d1db6abc93c9a7e0c5bbca01739d8356/ros/include/Node.h#L35) includes a header  `"orb_slam2_ros/SaveMap.h"`, but it's not included in the repo. The package builds completely fine. Is the header generated? If so, how is it generated?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333041/where-is-this-header-file?/) by [mun](https://answers.ros.org/users/44890/mun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`orb_slam2_ros/SaveMap` is a [service](http://wiki.ros.org/Services), which is defined in [appliedAI-Initiative/orb_slam_2_ros/srv/SaveMap.srv](https://github.com/appliedAI-Initiative/orb_slam_2_ros/blob/e978a2c1d1db6abc93c9a7e0c5bbca01739d8356/srv/SaveMap.srv).

All ROS service definitions are processed by code generators which -- in the case of C++ -- generate header files for them.

See [these lines](https://github.com/appliedAI-Initiative/orb_slam_2_ros/blob/e978a2c1d1db6abc93c9a7e0c5bbca01739d8356/CMakeLists.txt#L65-L73) for where the service is registered and the code generators are invoked.

> it's not included in the repo.

as should now be clear: the header file is generated during the build, so is not part of the repository.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1